# How to resolve spinlock issues with multithreaded python?

Tags: python, multithreading, spinlock

I'm writing a multithreaded application in Python and have came across an issue where kernel time skyrockets. Using `perf` I see that it is indeed a spinlock:

```
  54.89%         python  [kernel.kallsyms]            [k] __ticket_spin_lock
```

The code that causes the spinlock is below:

```
for i in range(0, my_uuids_len):
    while threading.active_count() >= concurrency:
      time.sleep(0.1)

    threading.Thread(target=read_benchmark,args=(read_times,my_uuids.pop(),)).start()
    counter += 1
```

Comment: No wonder you spend time there, spinlocks are intended to wait while you can't progress. Have you tried raising the `concurrency` limit?

Comment: Try not using spinlocks unless... actually, nothing.

Comment: The whole point of spinlocks is to avoid expensive kernel calls - calling `sleep` inside one is obviously not a good idea. Also spinlocks are a low-level performance optimization you shouldn't use in your code yourself, that's for the library that implements the `wait/notify` (which is what you really want here) to do.

Comment: @josten Overlooked the perf entry and ended up focusing on your shown loop - the while loop should be rewritten to avoid all those unnecessary context switches. Doesn't explain your spin lock calls themselves though.

Comment: Which Python implementation are you using, and can you identify *which* spinlock is your code spinning on?

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know which spinlock this is but how many threads do you start?

How about not starting threads but processes?

have a look at multiprocessing or in Python 3.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor # should do exactly what your code does now
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor # I recommend that
```

If the `ProcessPoolExecutor` does not resolve the problem then the switches between the Python threads should not be the problem.

Comment: Hm can you have 5000 threads in C-Python? I thought you can only have 800+something.

Comment: Is it resolved when you use processes? Then it can be an issue of the Python-internal threading. I did not clearly see that we know the source of the issue.