# time.sleep() function

Tags: python, tornado

I am just trying to understand that if when I call time.sleep(x), the current thread that is running the code gets delayed by x seconds. But does that free up the processor for those x seconds or does the thread keep the resources to itself and after x seconds it just starts executing the next lines of code.

Editing with the exact scenario I am facing:

Here's the case with me:

```
class SomeHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler)
  @tornado.gen.coroutine
  def something_async():
    time.sleep(5)
    return result

  def on_message(message):
    future = yield something_async(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', SomeHandler),
  ])

  http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
  http_server.listen(8888)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Now since this Tornado will be a single threaded server, What exactly does time.sleep(5) do in this case (will it just block the thread for 5 seconds making the whole process synchronous) or the coroutine spawns a new thread?

Comment: Would it make sense to hog the CPU and prevent any other thread from executing? Is there perhaps a way you could find out?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92928/time-sleep-sleeps-thread-or-process

Comment: The simple answer is that it will free the processor, but the implementation might vary.  There is a feature known as a *spin lock* whereby a thread retains the CPU if the wait is for a short time.  It is conceivable that an implementation could use a spin lock for short sleep times, particularly on Windows where there is an API specifically for that.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273474/behavior-of-pythons-time-sleep0-under-linux-does-it-cause-a-context-switch and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115831/how-to-resolve-spinlock-issues-with-multithreaded-python

Answer (score 3):

An example is always best:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8; py-indent-offset:4 -*-
###############################################################################
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
#                        unicode_literals)

import threading
import time


def func1():
    time.sleep(10)
    print('Func1: Out of sleep and returning')


def func2(flag):
    while not flag:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Func2: looping')

    print('Func2: Flag set, leaving')


t1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
f = list()

t2 = threading.Thread(target=func2, kwargs=dict(flag=f))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
f.append(None)
```

With output:

```
Func2: looping
Func2: looping
Func2: looping
Func2: looping
Func2: looping
Func2: looping
Func2: looping
Func2: looping
Func2: looping
Func1: Out of sleep and returning
Func2: looping
Func2: Flag set, leaving
```

It should be obvious from the output that even if `t1` (the 1st thread) is blocked in a long `time.sleep` of `10` seconds, the 2nd thread `t2` is running.

And even when `t1` is done we see that the main thread is able to `append` to the list which is being used as a `flag` to let `t2` understand it has to return and therefore end.

So: `time.sleep` only blocks the thread in which is being executed.

Comment: Thanks mementum for the detailed example. I've just added the whole scenario I am in, can you please comment on that?

Comment: As commented by others and seeing your full code now, the problem is you are blocking the main thread. Use the hint suggested by A. Jesse Jiryu Davis

Answer (score 2):

Tornado never spawns a thread for you.* If you call time.sleep, it blocks the entire process for the duration of the sleep; no other processing proceeds. This is why the docs say ["time.sleep should not be used in coroutines because it is blocking"](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.sleep). To explicitly pause a coroutine and return control to the IOLoop so other processing can proceed:

```
yield gen.sleep(0.5)
```

* Tornado can spawn threads for DNS resolution or when you explicitly use a ThreadPoolExecutor to make a task asynchronous. But you can ignore these cases for this discussion.

Comment: One another little problem, what if I want to use yield gen.sleep(0.5) in some function that is already returning a value? Python < 3.3 doesn't support that. What else can be done in that case?

Comment: To return a value from a coroutine in Python 2, "raise gen.Return(value)":

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.Return

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you write a brief example to explain?
    '
    def add(x,y):
      yield gen.sleep(countdown);
      a = x+y;
      raise gen.Return(a);
How to get the value a by calling this function?

Comment: Sure! Everything you need to know is written here:

https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/

Answer (score 0):

**you can use the code inside function:**

```
import time
time.sleep(2) # put value here as seconds, 2 is 2 seconds
```

**OR**

```
from time import sleep
sleep(60) # put value here as seconds, 60 is 60 seconds = 1 minute
```

**Example code:**

```
import time
def function1():
    print('function1 is sleeping for 2 seconds...')
    time.sleep(2)

count = 0
while True:
    if count >= 10:
        break
    function1()
    count=count+1
```

**For further details please visit :** https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep